# How can I exclude regex matches inside blocks with a certain attribute?

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-negation

I am trying to match all tags except for tags inside textareas that have the "data-do-not-match-this='true'" attribute. Given I have this test string:

```
<textarea>{{one}}{{two}}</textarea> 

<textarea data-do-not-match-this="true">{{three}}{{four}}</textarea> 

<textarea>
{{five}}
{{six}}{{seven}}
</textarea> 

<textarea data-do-not-match-this="true">
{{eight}}
{{nine}}{{ten}}
</textarea>

{{eleven}}{{twelve}}
```

I have this regex so far:

```
(?<!data\-do\-not\-match\-this="true">)({{.*?}})
```

The regex incorrectly matches {{four}}, {{eight}}, {{nine}}, and {{ten}}. How can I fix the regex to exclude tags I do not want to match?

This is my Rubular:

https://rubular.com/r/TfjuwRd8dSjFJX

Comment: I think that XPath is much more appropriate for this sort of extraction.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/179125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hard…

```
(?:<textarea data-do-not-match-this="true">.+?<\/textarea>.*?)?({{.*?}})
```

https://rubular.com/r/32MFMtZ2Ms3lOX

Comment: Wow! Great solution. Works perfect :) Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

```
<textarea[^>]+data-match-this="[^"]+"[^>]*>.*?<\/textarea>
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry Tim. I forgot to add tags outside of the textarea too. I modified the question above with the updated Rubular.

Comment: How does your question change (I'm not seeing any change)?  Can you edit your question and show us exactly what you are trying to match?

Comment: Yes, does this Rubular make more sense: https://rubular.com/r/emay1eMo8FWlVQ? Basically, I'm trying to exclude all tags inside "textarea" blocks unless it has the data-match-this="true" attribute. If it's easier, we can modify the test string to use something like do-not-data-match-this="true" instead.

Comment: My regex identifies all text which you want to keep, if I understand correctly.  Then, why can't you just iterate your text file and retain only the portions which match?